# How to find type without using instanceof?

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a `List` of interface type `Criteria` within my class `Query`.

```
List<Criteria> criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
```

I have several concrete implementations of `Criteria`. I want to give `Query` a method that iterates through my `criteria` list, and depending on the concrete type, execute some logic.

I'm presently doing this with `instanceof` like so:

```
for(Criteria c : criteria) {
    if(c instanceof ContextualCriteria){
        // logic
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this the only/best way?

Comment: Maybe you could define behaviour in `Criteria` and let the objects perform the logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the logic sensibly belong in the `Criteria` itself? If so, put it into the `Criteria` interface and implement it appropriately for each concrete class implementing the `Criteria` interface. This is obviously the *nice* polymorphic approach.

Unfortunately, in real life OO doesn't always work as simply as that - sometimes it doesn't make sense to put the per-type behaviour in the type itself, so you may need to use `instanceof` instead. You could *potentially* have a map from "criteria class" to some interface representing the action to take, but that could easily end up being even messier.

Double-dispatch via the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can *sometimes* improve things a little - so the logic could still be in separate methods in your "calling" class, but each `Criteria` can call *back* to the right method via a single interface method. Personally I tend to find this increases coupling and gets ugly quickly, but others swear by it.

Comment: unfortunately, the logic doesn't fit within `Criteria`. I agree, the two alternatives you provided are less concise.

Comment: what stigma surrounds `instanceof` ?

Comment: @wulfgar.pro: It's slightly dogmatic, in my view - ignoring the fact that life doesn't always work out in the most OO way we might like. Polymorphism is preferable where possible, but it doesn't *always* help.

Answer (score 3):

If the logic does not belong in the Criteria as Jon Skeet suggests, then you could use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

In ConcreteCriteria:

```
public void accept(CriteriaVisitor v) {
    v.visit(this);
}
```

In the Client code:

```
public void method() {
    for (Criteria c : criteria) {
        c.accept(this);
    }
}

public void visit(ConcreteCriteria c) {
    // do logic here
}

public void visit(Criteria c) {
    // othervise...
}
```

This gets rid of the instanceof, but be wary, I have found that this pattern is difficult to understand if you are unfamiliar with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can...

```
if (ContextualCriteria.class.equals(c.getClass()) {
```

... though it's just a fancier-looking way of writing `instanceof`. (Well, almost: this tests whether it is exactly the class, rather than the class of a subclass -- for that you want `isAssignableFrom()`).

The right way to get rid of the smell is to implement a polymorphic method in `Criteria` which is overridden in subclasses, for example.

Comment: As said in my comment to Kublai: no this is **not** the same as instanceof. You will not match any subclasses

Comment: Right, which is what I said in my response. He wants to execute logic based on the particular class. It would actually be wrong, probably, to execute based on class-or-subclass -- you might match class B in the clause for A, when you meant A. My answer is quite intentional; I don't think your reasoning for marking it down is valid.

Comment: @Sean Owen - the polymorphic way was my original implementation - yet, the logic in `Query` doesn't properly fit within the `Criteria` implementations =(.

Answer (score 1):

An interface is halfway to the strategy pattern! To vary the logic based on type, push it behind the interface if possible, such that Criteria has a doLogic(). You can pass that method whatever parameters you might need to alter in the calling code, or return new information - that is very implmentation specific and hard to advice on from the code in question.

If all goes well, your calling code ends up

```
for (Criteria c : criteria) {
    c.doLogic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement the logic in the classes which implement Criteria

```
public interface Criteria {
  public void logic();
}
```

Have several implemetations in classes like ContextualCriteria
And your loop would look clean:

```
for(Criteria c : criteria) {  
   c.logic();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
for(Criteria c : criteria) {
   if(c.getClass() == ContextualCriteria.class){
       // logic
   }
   if ...
}
```

Note that [Object#getClass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) returns the runtime type of `c`, so you can't reliably use this if `ContextualCriteria` can be subclassed for example. To do this you would need to use [Class#isAssignableFrom()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
for(Criteria c : criteria) {
   if(ContextualCriteria.class.isAssignableFrom(c)){
       // logic
   }
   if ...
}
```

Comment: is this a better approach? Why?

Comment: This is not the same: your test will match only this specific class while `instanceof` will also match subclasses.

Comment: @wulfgar - This is not necessarily better; I'm just showing other ways per your question. Jon Skeet's answer is the best in terms of meaningful discussion.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it.

People who never used `instanceof` only wrote toy applications.