# Decide type of request class?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have below three classes.

```
SuperClass.java
SubClass1 extends SuperClass
SubClass2 extends SuperClass
```

I have a method which will accept the method parameter of type `SuperClass`.

```
getResult(SuperClass request){
//Here the request can be of SubClass1 type or SubClass2 type.

}
```

Here the `request` can be either `SubClass1` type or `SubClass2` type.

Inside `getResult()` method based on type of request i need to do some logic.

To find out the type i can use `instanceof` operator as below.

```
if(request instanceof SubClass1){
//do something
}else if(request instanceof SubClass2){
//dosomething
}
```

Is there any best way to find out the type of request?

Thanks!

Comment: there is nothing **instance of** in java.But **instanceof** is there

Comment: The best way is not to use instanceof as it in most cases points to design smell. Think about your design once again. The amount of snippets you have provided are not enough to suggest something else IMHO.

Comment: @NarendraPathai, Thanks for your response. Basically my super class is going to have some common properties. My idea is instead of having two separate methods which will accept subclass1 and subclass2, am planning to have single method with parameter of type superclass..

Comment: The only reason instanceof is discouraged is because it shows that the polymorphic behavior is not properly utilized, and is somewhat like non OO programming. But that does not mean you never have to use it, there are some conditions where you use it, read @Jon Skeet's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453288/how-to-find-type-without-using-instanceof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

> The only reason instanceof is discouraged is because it shows that the
>   polymorphic behavior is not properly utilized, and is somewhat like
>   non OO programming. But that does not mean you never have to use it,
>   there are some conditions where you use it.

### Runtime Polymorphism

Now you can utilize Overriding (Runtime polymorphism) which is a proper way to do things.

```
abstract class SuperClass{
   public abstract Result getResult();
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{
   @Override
   public Result getResult(){
      //logic
   }
}


class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{
   @Override
   public Result getResult(){
      //logic
   }
}

//calling 

getResult(SuperClass request){
   Result r = request.getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid `instanceof` keyword.

> The reason instanceof is discouraged is that it's not OOP.
>   There should be no reason for the caller/user of an object to know which concrete class it is an instance of beyond which type the variable it is declared as.
>   If you need different behavior in subclasses add a method and implement them differently.

Basic way: I would write something like:

```
enum Types{ SUB_1, SUB_2 }

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{
  public Types type = Types.SUB_1;
} 

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{
  public Types type = Types.SUB_2;
}
```

and:

```
if(Types.SUB_1 == request.type){
  //do something
}else if(Types.SUB_2 == request.type){
  //do something
}
```

Proper way (from my sight) I would use polymorphism in your case.

**Polymorphism**  - The same message sent to different objects, results in behavior that is dependent
on the nature of the object receiving the message.

Means:

```
 public interface SuperClassItf{
  public void doStuff();
 }

 public class SubClass1 extends SuperClassItf{
     public void doStuff(){
          // do 1
       }
    } 

    public class SubClass2 extends SuperClassItf{
     public void doStuff(){
        // do 2
     }
    }
```

**Main**

```
getResult(SuperClassItf request){
   request.doStuff(); //polymorphic method call
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me why using instanceof keyword is discouraged? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I don't understand this too. What is the benefit from using instanceof here?

Comment: because `instanceof` is very slow.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/184109/replacement-for-instanceof-java

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry do you have benchmarks for what you suggest? instanceof was slow in Java 1.3 days and has improved a lot.

Comment: @NarendraPathai here in Russian, but you could see only graphs. http://habrahabr.ru/post/118087/

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry thanks, it makes sense, however we talk not about performance but code design.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the getResult() in an interface and let the logic do in abstract SuperClass concrete subclasses?

```
public interface ResultProvider {
    public Result getResult();
}

public abstract class SuperClass implements ResultProvider {
    ...
}

public SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
    public Result getResult() {
        ...
    }
}

public SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
    public Result getResult() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: could u please tell me why using instanceof operator is discouraged? Thanks!

Comment: If this is same as instanceof and you are asking a question in the answer. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have run time polymorphism. Here is sample code for you.

```
public class SuperClass
{
public void doSomething(){}
}
public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{
  public void doSomething(){}
} 

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{
  public void doSomething(){}
}

getResult(SuperClass request){

 request.doSomething();

}
```

Comment: Abstract class is totally fine , it can have non abstract methods too.

Comment: @user755806 Not really, in fact it's probably better for the methods whose implementation changes between subclasses to be `abstract`